# getting ddl from database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can i get all ddls from database i don't want to get one by one .

Comment: Yes, of course. And now, please provide more information about what database are you using, sql client, etc.

Comment: i am currently using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just follow the steps:-

First right click on database,

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=7593)

Select your database, *right click->Tasks->Generate Script*